# How can I do a batch file to copy and rename a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to create a batch file to copy a "folder" as a backup to a new destination. However, I need to add a date stamp of the file name.

for example folder is myFolder when I copy it I want to to be named myFolder_todays_date

I want to be able to copy the folder and it's content.

I found the xCopy but I am not sure how to write it correctly.

now I tried xCopy /e/i dir newDir

How can I append the date to the folder name?

I appreciated your help on how to write this batch file correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
mkdir %1%DATE%
xcopy /s %1 %1%DATE%
```

This accepts the name of the folder as a command line argument.

For example if the above batch file is called bkup.bat and you want to make a backup of a directory called work, you run it as

```
bkup.bat work
```

It copies it into the current directory. You can accept a 2nd command line argument (%2) & also use that if you want to copy to a different directory

```
xcopy /s %1 %2\%1%DATE%
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't seems to follow your instruction. I tried mkdir %1%DATE% it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: @Mike What error? Are you trying this from a batch file or directly. If from a batch file - what command line arguments are you passing while invoking the batch file

Comment: @Mike - try `echo %1%DATE%` in the batch file with same command line args passed - what do you get?